# Spring Controller 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: angularjs, spring, angular-http

I am getting bad request issue from spring controller. (Reason : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.) 
Below is my rest call :

**Requested payload:**

```
categoty: "Game"
itemDescription: "adas"
itemDiscount: 1
itemName: "asdas"
itemPrice: 1
itemQuantity: 1
```

**Rest Method**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/addItem", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
 public  @ResponseBody String createItem(@RequestBody Item item) {

     ItemDAO itemDAO=new ItemDAO(item);      

     try{
         itemDAO.createProduct();
         return "Success";
     }catch(Exception e){  
         System.out.println("Exception occured in item update");
         e.printStackTrace();
         return "Exception occured in item add";
     }  

 }
```

**Model (Just properties)**

```
@Entity  
@Table(name= "Item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id; 
    private String itemName,itemDescription,categoty;   
    private double itemPrice;
    private float itemDiscount;
    private int itemQuantity;
}
```

**Markup**

```
 <div data-ng-show="show=='addProduct'">  
      <p class="{{errorClass}}">{{newProductError}}</p> 
      <h2>Add an Item</h2>
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Item Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input  class="form-control"  placeholder="Item Name" ng-model="newItem.itemName">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Item Description</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input  class="form-control"  placeholder="Item Description" ng-model="newItem.itemDescription">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Item Price</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input  class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Item Price"  ng-model="newItem.itemPrice">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Item Discount</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">          
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Item Discount" ng-model="newItem.itemDiscount">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Item Quantity</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">          
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Item Quantity" ng-model="newItem.itemQuantity">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Item Category</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input  class="form-control"  placeholder="Item Category" ng-model="newItem.categoty">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addItem();">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
```

**Service**

```
addItem: function(item){
    return $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/Ecomm-Java-Backend/item/addItem',
        data: item,
        heades:{
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).success(function(result){
        console.log(result.length);
        console.log("result success "+ result);
        return result;
    }).error(function(err){
        console.log("result success "+ err);
        return err;
    });     
}
```

When I invoke the rest call , I'm getting bad request error.

What could be the issue here? Any help would appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo `heades`, change it `headers`

Comment: also you missed to add `name` attribute to form elments

Comment: Changed it , but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addItem", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public  @ResponseBody String createItem(@RequestBody Item item) {

         ItemDAO itemDAO=new ItemDAO(item);      

         try{
             itemDAO.createProduct();
             return "Success";
         }catch(Exception e){  
             System.out.println("Exception occured in item update");
             e.printStackTrace();
             return "Exception occured in item add";
         }  

     }
```

and this in your client side

```
    addItem: function(item){
        return $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/Ecomm-Java-Backend/item/addItem',
            data: {
     categoty: "Game" ,
     itemDescription: "adas", 
     itemDiscount: 1 ,
     itemName: "asdas",
     itemPrice: 1,
     itemQuantity: 1
// get values from item object
},
            headers : { 'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).success(function(result){
            console.log(result.length);
            console.log("result success "+ result);
            return result;
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log("result success "+ err);
            return err;
        });     
    }
```

Comment: Are you still  getting a 400 ?

Comment: Yes with cause : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Ok, that's good your JSON data  is not correct/ doesn't correspond to your server's Item object, put here your sample request  and the Item class

Comment: added reuest in the question and model (Item object definition is already present )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72524/discussion-between-iamiddy-and-user3440629).

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved
changed json data to

```
categoty: "Game"
description: "test1"
discount: 10
name: "Test"
price: 10
quantity: 10
```

But still can't figure out why this worked ...