# Spring Controller Rest Call Failure

Tags: java, spring, rest

I was making a rest call to Spring Controller, it failed to got through with BAD request (400 cause , original question [Spring Controller 400 (Bad Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930633/spring-controller-400-bad-request/28931324#28931324))

**My Initial rest call parameters were:**

```
categoty: "Game"
itemDescription: "adas"
itemDiscount: 1
itemName: "asdas"
itemPrice: 1
itemQuantity: 1
```

**This failed , but when I changed the parameters as below , it worked:**

```
categoty: "Game"
description: "test1"
discount: 10
name: "Test"
price: 10
quantity: 10
```

**My Persistence POJO class was :**

```
import javax.persistence.*;  

@Entity  
@Table(name= "Item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id; 
    private String itemName,itemDescription,categoty;   
    private double itemPrice;
    private float itemDiscount;
    private int itemQuantity;


    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(int id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  

    public int getQuantity() {  
        return itemQuantity;  
    }  
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {  
        this.itemQuantity = quantity;  
    }  

    public float getDiscount() {  
        return itemDiscount;  
    }  
    public void setDiscount(float discount) {  
        this.itemDiscount = discount;  
    }  

    public double getPrice() {  
        return itemPrice;  
    }  
    public void setPrice(double price) {  
        this.itemPrice = price;  
    }  
    public String getName() {  
        return itemName;  
    }  
    public void setName(String iName) {  
        this.itemName = iName;  
    }  
    public String getDescription() {  
        return itemDescription;  
    }  
    public void setDescription(String desc) {  
        this.itemDescription = desc;  
    }  
    public String getcategoty() {  
        return categoty;  
    }  
    public void setcategoty(String cat) {  
        this.categoty = cat;  
    }  


}
```

Can someone help me understand why second type of parameters worked , whereas first one didn't (Ideally first one was one to one mapping to properties in persistence class)?

Comment: it is the same to getters and setters, it removed the prefix name from all variables, Check these examples [example 1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-getters-and-setters.html) and [example 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143528/eclipse-generate-getter-setter-for-domain-objects-and-classmembers-with-m-suff)

Comment: It uses getters/setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring calls the setters of your Entity class. (property `quantity` --> `setQuantity(String)` - it doesn't look at the name of your members (e.g. `itemQuantity`).

**But**: it is always a good idea to name the setters/getter like your members. You should rename your members to match the getters and setter. That makes it more clear.

Besides that, `getcategoty` and `setcategoty` should be renamed to  camel-case `getCategory` and `setCategory`. BTW: is `categoty` a typo for `category`?

Answer (score 0):

It is the same to getters and setters, it removed the prefix name from all variables, Check the following links:

- [Generating Getters and
  Setters](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-getters-and-setters.html)
- [Eclipse generate getter/setter for domain objects and classmembers
  with 'm'
  suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143528/eclipse-generate-getter-setter-for-domain-objects-and-classmembers-with-m-suff)